# How do I fix this factory code and return the users w/a specific query

Tags: laravel, factory

```
$factory->define(App\Newsfeed::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'owner_id' => function () {
            return App\User::where('role_id', 3)->orWhere('role_id', 5)->first()->id;
        },
        'newsfeed_title' => $faker->catchPhrase,
        'body' => $faker->sentence(8,false)
        ];
});
```

with that code, I want to get shuffled results between two queries,but I only get like the first result w/ is user_id of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$factory->define(App\Newsfeed::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'owner_id' => function () {
            return App\User::whereIn('role_id', [3, 5])->get()->random()->id;
        },
        'newsfeed_title' => $faker->catchPhrase,
        'body' => $faker->sentence(8,false)
    ];
});
```

Should do the trick for you.